# How can I programmatically get and set column sorting parameters in AdvancedDataGrid?

Tags: advanceddatagrid

How can I programmatically get and set column sorting parameters in `AdvancedDataGrid`?

I'm especially interested in value that indicates that user have sorted data in `AdvancedDataGridColumn` by clicking on its header and value that indicates sorting order. I haven't found appropriate properties in `AdvancedDataGridColumn` documentation. There is only `sortDescending` property, but that's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the column object to the [getFieldSortInfo(column)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.html#getFieldSortInfo%28%29) method; it will give you a [SortInfo](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/SortInfo.html) object that has `status` (actual or proposed) and `descending` (boolean) variables that contain the information you need.

Comment: Thank you! But, how can I programmatically apply this sorting parameters to the AdvancedDataGridColumn?

Comment: @Sergey Use the [sortCompareFunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction)